# Wordpress order posts by first letter of title instead of full title

Tags: php, wordpress

When querying a custom post type, I need the results to be returned in "alphabetical" order by title with a secondary order using a numeric ACF field. At first I did the below and it worked as expected:

```
'meta_key' => 'sort_weight',
'orderby' => 'title meta_value_num',
```

However, since none of the post titles are identical, the secondary ordering is pointless. What I really need is to order by just the first letter of the title. This way, all the posts starting with "A" will show first in order of the ACF field, and then repeat for the rest of the letters, like:

```
Post title (weight)
AB (1)
AA (2)
BB (1)
BA (2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the standard wp_query to do what you're trying to do, I'm not sure how you would accomplish that. But, if I was in your shoes, I would create a custom postmeta field to use as the first search and you could automate it like this:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'vgs_save_sort_order', 10 );
function vgs_save_sort_order( $post_id ) {
    $sort_order = substr( get_the_title( $post_id ), 0, 1 );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_sort_order', $sort_order );
}
```

Then you could add multiple `orderby` parameters to the query, like this:

```
'orderby' => 'custom_sort_order ASC, sort_weight ASC',
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to avoid using another custom field, but your suggestion takes care of my main concern by having it automatically populate.